# My keyboard symbols layout changed

Tags: updates, keyboard, keyboard-layout

My keyboard symbols layout changed. I think this happened after I install some updates.
For example when I type:

-
- appears /

_ appears ?

= appears )

And this happens with all my characters.
I have already tried a lot of things nothing seams to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just like any laptop there is usually a key that makes the keyboard characters change or makes new characters appeared I were you I would go through your keys and see if anything works if not see if Ubuntu already has answered another question like this or look it up online.